# The minimum version of MySQL to support LIST COLUMNS partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning

What is the earliest version of MySQL supporting [LIST COLUMNS partitioning type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-list.html)? I've read [MySQL partitioning manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) which states it started supporting partitioning from version 5.1, but at the same time it has got no page referring to LIST COLUMNS partitioning type for that version. The minimum version in which MySQL has a reference manual for LIST COLUMNS is 5.5. Does that mean MySQL started supporting it since then? Or it's just that its manual was missing for 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns.html):
"The next two sections discuss COLUMNS partitioning, which are variants on RANGE and LIST partitioning that were introduced in MySQL 5.5.0."

"The discussions of RANGE COLUMNS and LIST COLUMNS partitioning in the next two sections assume that you are already familiar with partitioning based on ranges and lists as supported in MySQL 5.1 and later; [...]"

My guess would be that partitioning was added in 5.1 and the COLUMNS option was added in 5.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns.html says:

> The next two sections discuss COLUMNS partitioning, which are variants on RANGE and LIST partitioning that were introduced in MySQL 5.5.0.

That sentence is not written well.  The fact is that `RANGE` and `LIST` partitioning types were supported in 5.1, but the `RANGE COLUMNS` and `LIST COLUMNS` variants were introduced in 5.5.0.